# Já vi estas duas expressões , mas tenho dúvidas em qual a mais correta: "Atendimento público " ou "Atendimento ao público"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, português-europeu, significado-em-contexto, frases

"Atendimento público " ou "Atendimento ao público" Qual a forma mais correta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As duas estão corretas (embora "ao público" seja muito mais comum) mas, na minha opinião, têm significados distintos.

- **Atendimento ao público**: atendimento que é aberto à população — em oposição, por exemplo, ao "atendimento **interno**"; esse atendimento pode ser prestado por uma organização ligada ao não ao estado, ou seja, o "público" se refere *a quem* o atendimento é prestado.
- **Atendimento público**: aqui "atendimento" tende a ser um serviço, assim como "educação", e "público" está em oposição a **privado**, ou seja, não refere a quem o atendimento é prestado, mas a quem presta esse atendimento: o estado. Ex.: "[atendimento público ambulatorial](https://doi.org/10.1590/0102-311X00158612)".

Claro que há casos em que ambos os usos se sobrepõem. E o contexto, como de praxe, é importante aqui: se pode por exemplo falar de um "público interno" (pacientes de uma dada instituição, funcionários de uma dada empresa, sócios de um dado clube, etc.), caso em que "atendimento ao público" é efetivamente um atendimento interno. E o estado pode terceirizar um serviço seu, uma situação em que o serviço é simultaneamente "público" e "privado".